# chart.js doesn't show elements on line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working with a web application and I need to display a plot with data from the server. I use the [Chart.JS](http://www.chartjs.org/) library, but it doesn't work, only shows this: [image]

I load the data via JSON and this is the code I use

```
var labels = new Array();
var cpuLoad = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var cpuContext = document.getElementById("cpu").getContext("2d");

    $.getJSON("/pi/status/latest", function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data.response, function(index, status) 
        {
            labels.push(status.Status.fecha);
            cpuLoad.push(status.Status.cpu);
        });
    });

    var cpuData = 
    {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: "Carga CPU",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: cpuLoad
        }]
    };

    console.log(cpuData);

    var cpuChart = new Chart(cpuContext).Line(cpuData);
});
```

The .getJSON code works great but the graph doesn't show.
Here is an example of what data I'm passing to chart.js:

labels array:

[image: labels array]

cpuLoad array:

[image: cpuLoad array]

Comment: Which version of Chart.js are you using? If you hard-code a similar array into your dataset code, does your chart render?